# Error when using Jquery Scripts with Struts 2 Jquery Plugin

Tags: jquery, struts2, datepicker

I have been using certain aspects of the jquery plugin however i'd also like the freedom of using normal Jquery code when I hit a limitation/restriction in the Jquery plugin.

At the moment I can't seem to use normal Jquery date picker

```
<head>   
      <sj:head jquerytheme="redmond"/>     
        <s:head />
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title><s:text name="Home.title" /></title>  
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8" /> <!-- DO NOT REMOVE -->

        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <link href="/Project/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link type='text/css' href='/Project/css/confirm.css' rel='stylesheet' media='screen' />
        <link type='text/css' href='/Project/css/contact.css' rel='stylesheet' media='screen' />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/Project/js/blockUI.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/Project/js/jquery.simplemodal.js"></script> 
        <%-- <script type="text/javascript" src="/Project/js/confirm.js"></script>  --%>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/Project/js/contact.js"></script> 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/Project/js/watermark.js"></script> 
        <!--        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/validation.js"></script> -->
        <script type="text/javascript" >
```

Function for the date picker:

```
 jQuery(function($){
            date = "";
            $( '.datepicker' ).datepicker({
                dateFormat: 'yy/mm/dd',
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                minDate: '0',
                maxDate: '+20Y'
            });
        });
```

I get the error : `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'datepicker'`

Any suggestions?

Comment: It seems you haven't included the datepicker js file

Comment: @Patsy the Jquery ui is included via this tag: <sj:head jquerytheme="redmond"/>

Answer (score 1):

From your included script, I cannot see where's your jQuery and jQuery UI library, so try to put this after your included css:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

as well as you do not specified which element `$(this)` should point to, try to use specific `class` or `id`, for example:

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
```

if you give your element class `datepicker`.

Comment: this is included with the <sj:head jquerytheme="redmond"/>